# jenkins upload directory and subdirectories to s3 using withaws

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I need to upload files located on jenkins build workspace to s3
The folder named formated_files and it contains two sub-folders, dir1 and dir2
I am using withAws as followed:

```
withAWS(credentials: 'my-credentials', region: 'us-east-1') {
 s3Upload(file:'formated_files', includePathPattern:'**/*.json', 
 bucket:'my_bucket',path:'bucket_folder/')
}
```

Where I am going wrong here ?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No
It just doesn't do anything